# Assigning to [custom typdef] from incompatible type 'int'

Tags: c++, c, enums, typedef

In a method in my main.c file, I declare the variable irq_raised, which is of the type irq_type. I've defined irq_type in a typedef in another file and #import it at the top of main.c.

```
typedef enum
{
  IRQ_NONE = 0x0000,
  IRQ_VBLANK = 0x0001,
  IRQ_HBLANK = 0x0002,
  IRQ_VCOUNT = 0x0004,
  IRQ_TIMER0 = 0x0008,
  IRQ_TIMER1 = 0x0010,
  IRQ_TIMER2 = 0x0020,
  IRQ_TIMER3 = 0x0040,
  IRQ_SERIAL = 0x0080,
  IRQ_DMA0 = 0x0100,
  IRQ_DMA1 = 0x0200,
  IRQ_DMA2 = 0x0400,
  IRQ_DMA3 = 0x0800,
  IRQ_KEYPAD = 0x1000,
  IRQ_GAMEPAK = 0x2000,
} irq_type;
```

I can assign this variable to one of these like so:

```
irq_raised = IRQ_NONE;
```

However, when I attempt to do the following:

```
irq_raised |= IRQ_HBLANK;
```

I get the error:

```
Assigning to 'irq_type' from incompatible type 'int'
```

Why is this?

Comment: What exactly do you jave main.c is a file not a class - is it C++ or C they differ or Objective C which is the only language that uses #import. Your do loop does not finish. The update method is a macro  ...... None of these are standard so is very difficult to understand

Comment: Saying it is a class was just a typo. #import works in C++ and C, especially since I am writing the files in Xcode. I only showed the part of the do loop that applies, thus the ellipses (...) at the end.

Comment: Please, clarify the language mess. You say you have `main.c`, which would indicate plain C, but the error you speak of only occurs in C++  and the fact that #import works seems to indicate it's getting compiled as Objective C++ anyway. Do you perhaps have a setting in XCode that overrides the language choice? Providing the compiler invocation command that XCode uses would help (I am sure you can dig it up from the build log somewhere).

Comment: I've changed the entire question to better reflect what the problem is. Maybe this will make it clearer.

Comment: Let me guess: You're compiling as C++, aren't you?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In C++ you cannot assign an int directly to an enumerated value without a cast.  The bitwise OR operation you are performing results in an int, which you then attempt to assign to a variable of type `irq_type` without a cast.  It is the same problem as you would have here:

```
irq_type irq = 0;  // error
```

You can cast the result instead:

```
irq_type irq = IRQ_NONE;
irq = (irq_type)(irq | IRQ_HBLANK);
```

Relevant info from the specification:

> An enumerator can be promoted to an integer value. However, converting an integer to an enumerator requires an explicit cast, and the results are not defined.

Comment: That was the issue, thanks! What document was that info from?

Comment: @RileyTestut: That is from a recent C++ spec (draft) that I found.

Comment: @RileyTestut: [Here is a link](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2005/n1905.pdf) to a 2005 draft (not very recent, still relevant, and more recent drafts are available).  Look to page 129 where they go over the relationship between an enumerated type and its underlying integral type.